# Excel VBA using SQL to update rows on 1 worksheet from another worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've recently been introduced to using SQL to select data from one worksheet and writing it to another in the same workbook.  It's fantastic and as a result I've been able to save a user 2 hours with just one feature in their macro.

I'm working on another part and would like to update 1 field on 1 worksheet with the values from another field on a different worksheet (same workbook).

I'm getting a "syntax error in UPDATE statement" error message.  This is the code I'm using based on a similar query in Access (that works).

```
vsql = "UPDATE [HRFILE$] JOIN [LOB$] ON ([HRFILE$].[ID] = [LOB$].[ID]) AND ([HRFILE$].[ID] = [LOB$].[ID]) SET [HRFILE$].[MyLOB] = [LOB$].[LOB]"
```

I validated that the table names and field names are correct.  My guess is periods, brackets, and / or quotes is the issue.  I've tried a number of different combinations all with the same error message.

The SELECT queries are working great and are a big time saver for me.  I expect to use SQL for UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and APPEND queries in the future in the Excel macros.  We used to loop through the data but this is much faster.

The HRFILE worksheet has 20,000 rows and the LOB worksheet has 3,300 rows.

The HRFILE looks like this:

```txt
EmployeeA  Category A
EmployeeA  Category B
EmployeeA  Category C
EmployeeA  Category D
EmployeeA  Category E
EmployeeA  Category F
EmployeeB  Category A
EmployeeB  Category B
EmployeeB  Category C
EmployeeB  Category D
EmployeeB  Category E
EmployeeB  Category F
EmployeeC  Category A
EmployeeC  Category B
EmployeeC  Category C
EmployeeC  Category D
EmployeeC  Category E
EmployeeC  Category F
```

There are 19 columns on this worksheet.  ID is just one of the columns.  Each employee has 6 rows (1 for each category).  Each employee has the identical categories in the identical order.

The LOB file looks like this:

```
ID  STATUS HDEPT
1    A      222
5    T      115
100  A      100
```

This is the code I'm using.  It works but it is painfully slow.  It has been running for about 30 minutes.

```vb
Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook

dBconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & wbMain.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0"";"
    
Set dBcn = New ADODB.Connection
    
dBcn.Open dBconn
    
vsql = ""
vsql = "UPDATE [HRFILE$] hr INNER JOIN [LOB$] lb ON hr.[ID] = lb.[ID] SET hr.LINEOFBUS = lb.HDEPT"
    
Set dBrs = dBcn.Execute(vsql)
```

Any suggestions or resources you could point to that would help resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.......

Comment: `([HRFILE$].[ID] = [LOB$].[ID]) AND ([HRFILE$].[ID] = [LOB$].[ID])` looks like this is repeated?

Comment: @TimWilliams............I developed the same query in Access and that was the SQL.  I tried in  Excel.  I'll remove the duplication and see if I get any better results.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
vsql = " UPDATE [HRFILE$] hr JOIN [LOB$] l ON " & _
       " (hr.[ID] = l.[ID]) " & _
       " SET hr.[MyLOB] = l.[LOB] "
```

Edit: this completed in about 7secs, 29k records on Sheet5, about 3k on Sheet4

```vb
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sPath, t, sSQL As String, lngRecs As Long, sConn

    t = Timer
    
    sSQL = " update [Sheet5$] a inner join [Sheet4$] b on " & _
           " (a.[Id] = b.[Id]) " & _
           " set a.[LINEOFBUS] = b.[LINEOFBUS]"
    
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    `
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;ReadOnly=False;HDR=YES"";"
    
    oConn.Open sConn

    oConn.Execute sSQL, recordsaffected:=lngRecs, Options:=adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
    
    Debug.Print lngRecs & " updated in " & Timer - t
```

Comment: @timwilliams.........Thanks...........Still getting the syntax error message

Comment: Maybe share the headers in your Excel tables? And maybe a little more of your code or a description of exactly what the SQL is doing ( I know it seems obvious but still...).

Comment: @timwilliams.......Thanks for your help.  I've edited the question to show some sample data and the code I'm using.  It's working kind of....it's painfully slow.  I'm guessing it ran for 30 minutes and updated 16,500 records.  

I'm also getting a "Method 'Execute' of object "_Connection" failed" error message now.

Comment: @timwilliams........One other thing I noticed is that the HRFILE worksheet will have some employees that aren't on the LOB worksheet.  Can this be a part of the problem?  Thanks for all of your help and sharing your knowledge and experience.......

Comment: Something is wrong if the code has been running for 30min...

Comment: @timwilliams.......i agree with that.  The SELECT queries I've used are super faster on a lot bigger data sets

Comment: @joej..........You helped me with another SQL questions with Excel.  I was wondering if you have suggestions for this issue?  thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: @timwilliams............Thanks for your help.  I tried your edited answer and am getting the same thing.  It just runs and runs and says Excel is not responding.  I'm running this off of my C:\ drive since the file is so large (66,219 (kb).  If I try and open it on the VPN, it takes forever.  

I looked at the Task Manager and saw Excel is using 17 % of the CPU.  I'm wondering if this file is corrupted.  The 7 seconds for completion is what I expected based on the SELECT query results.  

I'm going to open a new workbook and copy everything over and see if that helps....

Comment: @timwilliams.........I think I may have a data issue..........I discovered that the some IDs on the LOB are duplicated.  The only difference between the 2 lines is a status (either A or T).  I'm guessing you didn't have this situation in your test.  I'm going to try and add a WHERE clause to the SQL to see if that makes a difference.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: @timwilliams.........Not sure what is going on.  I reviewed the data and made sure the IDs were on both tabs.  Tried again and still got the same results.  My guess is this update query is either kicking off a security application or there is some conflict with another application.  I may have to look for another solution....Thanks for all of your help and suggestions.......'

Comment: Any active event handlers on the sheet being updated?

Comment: @timwilliams...........Nope.  The last test was in a new workbook.  The only code in the workbook was your code to update the line of business field.

Comment: OK then there's something very different between your file and my test - certainly my test file was nowhere near the size of your file.